# JPHP giving out an Object

Tags: php

I am using JPHP to create a form. I have 2 forms. One with label, and other with input field and button. This is an one app, but different forms. The process is simple: When button clicked, app gets an string from the input field, and adds it to existing string in the label.

But when all is done, to my label adds just "Object". Im sorry if i am doing anything wrong, just trying to learn something about it :)

The code of the form with input field:

The *edit* is the input field.

Why it is returning "Object", not the actual string?

`class SetTableName extends AbstractForm
{

```
/**
 * @event button.click 
 */
function doButtonClick(UXMouseEvent $e = null)
{
    
    
    // Generated
    $e = $event ?: $e; // legacy code from 16 rc-2
    
    $GLOBALS['tableName'] = $this->edit;
    Element::appendText($this->form('MM')->label, $GLOBALS['tableName']);
    app()->hideForm('SetTableName');
}
```

}
`

I was trying to get this result:

the input form
[image: the input form]

the result
[image: the result]

But in reality:
[image: sad reality]

Comment: Maybe you need to call toString() or equivalent on the object?

Comment: The [last commit](https://github.com/jphp-group/jphp) to JPHP was over three years ago, the project really looks dead. Are you sure you want to continue with it? Also, there was a [question about JPHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77411087/231316) by another username yesterday, was that you?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, you need to assign the text value of the input field to `$GLOBALS['tableName']`. You can do this by accessing the text property of the input field like this >>

```
class SetTableName extends AbstractForm {

    /**
     * @event button.click 
     */
    function doButtonClick(UXMouseEvent $e = null)
    {
        // Generated
        $e = $event ?: $e; // legacy code from 16 rc-2
        
        // Get the text value of the input field
        $GLOBALS['tableName'] = $this->edit->text;
        
        // Append the text value to the label
        Element::appendText($this->form('MM')->label, $GLOBALS['tableName']);
        
        // Hide the form
        app()->hideForm('SetTableName');
    }
}
```